# Get a value from Database According to the Member Name with vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a SQL table which looks like:

```
+-------------------+
| id   member   req |
+-------------------+
| 1    Jim      0   |
| 2    Mary     0   |
| 3    Hunter   0   |
+-------------------+
```

I need to get the `id` of a certain member through my vb.net application (WinForms) in Visual Basic 2010.

Lets say I wanted to get **Mary**'s `id`. What is the SQL query to return the `id` for **Mary**?

Whats the Query for that?

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Possible Query Code:

`'My.Settings.username` is the name I'm looking up in the database to get the member `id`.

`Dim SQLID As String = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE member= '"
                     & My.Settings.username & "'"
submitRequest(SQLID)
vagueID.Text = 'ID Here'`

Comment: Are you looking for the SQL statement or the whole stack?  If it is the whole stack that you desire, you need to be specify how you wish to display the data, the type of database engine, etc.

Comment: @NoAlias not sure what you mean but all i am trying to do is find the member id of the member specified from the database and display it in a vb.net label. I am updating a possible Query code that may explain it better.

Comment: What kind of database (Access/SQL/Oracle/MySQL/etc)?

Comment: @NoAlias MySQL Database

Comment: You might want to add your edit as an answer instead of editing the question if you've already solved it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`MySQLCon = New MySqlConnection
MySQLCon.ConnectionString = "Database=localhost;Data Source=host;User Id=root;Password=root"
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Try
    MySQLCon.Open()
    Dim SQLID As String = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE member='" & My.Settings.username & "'"
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(SQLID, MySQLCon)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
    While READER.Read
        vagueID.Value2 = READER.GetInt32("id")
    End While
    MySQLCon.Close()
    MySQLCon.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    'Do Something
End Try`

Answer (score 0):

First, download the [MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html).

Second, add a reference to the MySQL connection to your project.

Third, import the Namespace of which you'll be using many of the classes from to reduce typing (at top of .vb file):

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Finally in your Form's Load event handler (or other event handler where you wish to display the ID in the label):

```
'Change to your specific connection string.
Dim strConnectionString As String = "Database=YourDatabaseName;Data Source=localhost;User Id=YourUser;Password=YourPassword"

Dim sqlConnection As New MySqlConnection(strConnectionString)

Dim strCommandText = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE member = @Member"

'Assumes that the ID field is an INT type.  Use a Long type if the type is a BIGINT.
Dim intID as Integer

Try

    'Open the connection.
    sqlConnection.Open()

    'Create a command to get the ID.
    Dim sqlCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strCommandText, sqlConnection)

    'It is always a good idea to use parameters.
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Member", My.Settings.username)

    vagueID.Text = Convert.ToString(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar())

Catch ex As Exception
    'Error handling goes here.
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    'Always close the connection!
    sqlConnection.Close()
End Try
```